# Executing jquery code in gsp in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

I want to show some input fields in gsp code when checkbox is on. I use jquery for it.
I connect jquery script to gsp as follows:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
<script type="text/javascript">($('.isAdminCafee').click(function() {
  $('.adminFields')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
  });)
</script>
```

This is my part of my gsp-code, with this code jquery-script must be interact:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><g:checkBox name="isAdminCafee" value="${false}"/>
    Register as admin
  </label>
</div>
<div class="adminFields">
  hello)
</div>
```

But interaction doesn't happen. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkbox has its name set to `isAdminCafee`, not its class. Your jQuery selector `.isAdminCafee` searches by class and so does not match anything.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".adminFields").hide();
$('.checkbox input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $(".adminFields").show();
    } else {
        $(".adminFields").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="isAdminCafee" value="false">Register as admin</label>
</div>
<div class="adminFields">
  hello)
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but also neccessary do class name for checkbox as Gregor Petrin said and wrap jquery code into $(document).ready(function(){...}

Comment: Yes it should be wrap into the document ready part. But if you use the script part at the end, then you don't need to use the document ready part.

Comment: @pragmus You need not to add class name for checkbox if you use the above code.

Comment: may be. May be your code didn't work for me in the first time, because I connected jquery library in head-part and forgot to do the document ready part.